# mysql query to get the revenue, cost and profit from the below tables:

Tags: mysql

I have the below tables in database, I need to calculate the revenue(sum of sell price of all orders ), the cost (sum of all costs of all sold products) and the profit (the revenue minus the cost)

- sales_order

  ```
     id 
     grand_total (sum of sell_price of its items)
     order_status (pending/complete)
     delivery_date (date)
  ```
- sales_order_item

  ```
  id
  sales_order_id
  product_id (unique)
  quantity (ordered quantity)
  sell_price (sell price for single item)
  ```
- purchase_order

  ```
  id
  status (pending / approved)
  ```
- purchase_order_items

  ```
  id
  purchase_order_id
  product_id
  cost  (cost of each item)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining on your `sales_order_item` table to a distinct pull of cost and product from your `purchase_order_items` table should work assuming that `cost` isn't different between `purchase_orders` over time. If cost has changed then this could get a little ugly.

```
SELECT sum(sell_price*quantity) as revenue, sum(cost*quantity) as cost, sum(sell_price)-sum(cost*quantity) as profit
FROM sales_order_item 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct cost, product_id FROM purchase_order_items) as product 
        ON sales_order_item.product_id = product.product_id
```

Comment: I need to group them by sales_order.delivery_date

Comment: Then join in `sales_order` using `sales_order_item.sales_order_id = sales_order.id` add `delivery_date` to the select and at the bottom `GROUP BY sales_order.delivery_date`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. What do you suggest me to do if the cost change with time?

Comment: You'll have to either subquery the `purchase_order_items` table to grab the most recent cost per material and use that in the join, or you'll have to figure out how to join your orders to your purchase orders by date or date range which could get ugly, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the main question. The query works fine , but the revenue is doubled. Why?

Comment: It's most likely your data. I'm assuming that you have multiple `costs` for each `product_id` in your purchase_order_items. So you'll need to build a better subquery to determine which cost is the right cost to bring through so that each distinct product_id in that subquery has a single cost. If there is a date in that table then something like `(SELECT cost, product_id FROM purchase_order_items t1 WHERE datefield = (SELECT max(datefield) FROM purchase_order_items WHERE product_id = t1.product_id) as product` which will pick the last cost based on date of the purchase_order_item.

Comment: Amazing. The problem was Multiple costs. Thanks